# I just installed a Debian VM, and it's already occupying 5GB without installing anything

Tags: debian, disk-usage

im using debian 12 and run it via virtual box .
when i do df -h i can see it takes 5g , and i didn't install any thing yet ,
see :

```
umen@debian12:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            953M     0  953M   0% /dev
tmpfs           197M  1.2M  196M   1% /run
/dev/sda1       8.9G  5.0G  3.5G  59% /
tmpfs           984M     0  984M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           197M   64K  197M   1% /run/user/113
tmpfs           197M   56K  197M   1% /run/user/1000
```

how can i see what taking me so much space ?

Comment: Either you installed packages into the image for it to be a Debian VM, or you obtained a VM image of packages already installed.  In either case, `dpkg --list` will show all the packages currently installed.  How large would you expect an installed Debian system to be?  Have you tried removing packages you are not going to use to make the image smaller?